# Multiple Countdown timer on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdowntimer

I've created a page in which multiple countdown timers are added. But I want them to work only if a user is at the particular section like in a page dot navigation is added from which on click user is taken to that section using scroll effect, so in each section, there is a countdown timer, but that is working only once and each section value is updated, how to make countdown timer to work only when the user is at that particular section.

Here is the script

```
var a = 0;   
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var oTop = $('#counter{{loop.index}}').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
 
  if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
    $('.counter-value').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
      $({
        countNum: $this.text()
      }).animate({
          countNum: countTo
        },

        {

          duration: 2000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function() {
            $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
          },
          complete: function() {
            $this.text(this.countNum);
            //alert('finished');
          }

        });
    });
    a = 1;
  }

});
```

This is dynamic but if I have all different script for each section then also it is working same

```
var oTop = $('#counter{{loop.index}}').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
```

For this section Every section has equal height, I have checked it from alert($("#counter4").height());

From this .height() function

Comment: i dont think we could help you without the html/css code and the complete js code

Comment: `$('#counter{{loop.index}}')` is not js what is this?

Comment: For every section, there is a unique id given inside the for loop so the same id is added instead of repeating the code given dynamic id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can take an idea from this example it also has mutiple countdown timer and working on scroll
**https://www.cssscript.com/demo/scroll-triggered-counter/**